# R deleting duplicates in other columns

Tags: r

Hey guys I definitely solved this problem before but I lost my code...
Here is a simplification of what I have.

```
a1 <- c(1,2,4,3,5)
a2 <- c("a","b","b","c","f")
a3 <- c(3,4,"b",1,9)
a4 <- c("c","b",2,"a","d")
a <- cbind(a1,a2,a3,a4)
```

`a1` and `a2` are a set as well as `a3` and `a4`:

[image]

I would like to remove the duplicates. So remove rows 3 and 4. This data comes from a blast showing links between genomes and it is 34,000 rows long so a efficient solution would be great.

Thank you so much! I would also be open to doing this in another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `sort` the 'a' by row, get the logical index of not (`!`) `duplicated` elements and use that to filter the rows.

```
i1 <- !duplicated(t(apply(a, 1, sort)))
a1 <- a[i1,]
```

The index of rows that remains in the dataset are

```
which(i1)
#[1] 1 2 5
```